# Spark ML - StringType is not supported

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-ml

Here the sample code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.log4j._

Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans

val dataset = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("Online_Retail.csv")

val feature_data = dataset.select($"InvoiceNo", $"StockCode", $"CustomerID")

import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{VectorAssembler,StringIndexer,VectorIndexer,OneHotEncoder}
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors

val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("InvoiceNo", "StockCode", "CustomerID")).setOutputCol("features")

val training_data = assembler.transform(feature_data).select("features")
```

When code is run the below error is generated:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data type StringType is not supported
```

Anyone have any idea how to resolve this error?

When I tried with StringIndexer, following error triggered:

```
scala> val invoiceNoIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCols("InvoiceNo").setOutputCol("invoiceIndexer")
<console>:30: error: value setInputCols is not a member of org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer
val invoiceNoIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCols("InvoiceNo").setOutputCol("invoiceIndexer")
            ^
```

Comment: Please, *do not post code snippets & error messages in the comments* - they are unreadable... Edit & update your post instead!

Comment: Hello Eliasah,

My issue is different from the suggested by you. Can you please check it?

Comment: this is a different error than what you posted first : "value setInputCols is not a member of org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer" check here http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer